# AuthenticationManager.Login always returning false on Load balanced Environment

Tags: authentication

We have created an extranet user in Sitecore CMS to authenticate users in the CD website for the POST method.

Below is the code written for the same.

```
AuthenticationManager.Login(domain + @"\\" + username, password, true, false);
```

Even we tried to use below:

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(domain + "\\" + username, , password)
```

User is getting Authenticated in Standalone environment (DEV and Local) but on the scaled environment, with 2 CD servers, this method is always returning false even after passing admin user.

What I am missing here?

Comment: pl check if sticky session is enabled on Load balancer

Comment: Thanks Abhay for the response. Sticky session is enabled.

Comment: can u pl try once in incognito mode or use a  new browser

Answer (score 0):

In the CD `Web.config`, find the **"security:define"** app setting and change the value of the key from **"None"** to **"Sitecore"**.
It will fix the error.